# Невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "int" в "const vector &" (подчеркивает return rez) error C2664:

Tags: c++

```
class vector
{
private:

    int *mass;
    int size;
public:

    vector(int *array, int n)
    {
        size = n;
        mass = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            mass[i] = array[i];
        }
    }

    vector sum(vector B, int rez)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i=i+2)
        {
            rez = B.mass[i] + B.mass[i+1];
        }

        return rez;
    }

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int mass2[8];
    int k, r = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        int p;
        cout << "Введите для 1 вектора " << i + 1 << "значение" << endl;
        cin >> p;
        mass2[i] = p;
    }

    vector obj1(mass2, 8);
    vector obj2(mass2, 8);

    obj1.sum(obj2,r);
    cout << "Сумма двух векторов = " << r << endl;
}
```

Comment: Так а чего вы возвращение int а в функции vector написали? И переименуйте вектор, чтобы со стандартным классов меньше путали люди.

Comment: Во-первых, название "vector" - плохое. Просто потому, что подозрительно похоже на std::vector.

Во-вторых, из класса vector надо убрать все восьмёрки. size там на что?

В-третьих, метод sum() делает явно не "сумму двух векторов". Предлагаю для начала подумать, что именно должно получиться.

Answer (score 0):

Если принципиально сохранить параметры функции sum, то :

```
void sum(vector B, int &rez)
    {
        rez = 0; // убрать, если надо прибавлять сумму векторов к числу rez
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i=i+2)
        {
            rez += B.mass[i] + B.mass[i+1];// += чтобы сумму всех элементов получить
        }
    }
```

Если необходимо сделать именно возврат из функции, то:

```
int sum(vector B)
        {
            int rez = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i=i+2)
            {
                rez += B.mass[i] + B.mass[i+1];// += чтобы сумму всех элементов получить
            }
            return rez;
        }
```

И вызывать как:

```
r = obj1.sum(obj2,r);
```

Так же стоит посмотреть в сторону перегрузки операторов "+" и "+=". Возможно это то, что Вы хотите сделать.